# Jquery find() selector order and performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

For jQuery find(), does the order of the selector matter in performance?

i.e. do the two below code snippets run in the same time with the order of the selector being the only difference?

```
$('#commentList').find('.x-comment-no-edit.new-comment').each(function(){
    //Option 1
});

$('#commentList').find('.new-comment.x-comment-no-edit').each(function(){
    //Option 2
});


<div id="commentList">
    <div class="x-comment-no-edit"></div>
    <div class="x-comment-no-edit"></div>
    <div class="x-comment-no-edit new-comment"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you check it out yourself using https://jsperf.com?

Comment: didn't know jsperf existed, thanks for the heads up, trying it now

Comment: Assuming your browser supports `querySelectorAll`, it doesn't matter what order the classes are in.

Comment: Thanks @TonyScialo for letting us know about that kind of tool. I think your suggestion should be accepted as solution.

Comment: https://jsperf.com/jquery-find-selector-testing/1 looks like the second selector is faster. Should i put this as an answer or leave as a comment @Terry?

Comment: Based on my tests, both methods are just as likely to be faster than the other. The verdict is that you are probably micro-optimising ;) https://jsperf.com/selector-chain-test

Comment: haha ok @Terry, thanks for the help, curiosity just got the best of me for this one